# Problem with Jenkins "unknown command" Error

Tags: jenkins, automation, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Problem facing that Job name with `spaces`causes `"Unknown command"` error .

Comment: You should really provide more context around what command you are running and the full error if you want a more constructive answer.

Answer (score 1):

*I don't think you can have spaces in your jenkins job. Cause jenkins create folders in the name of jobs and not all scripts you try to run, handle whitespaces well.*

[*Workspace Whitespace Replacement*](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ws-ws-replacement/) *is a simple Jenkins plug-in that allows job to be created with spaces in their name, but when the job is carried out on a slave node, the path used will have all spaces replaced by an underscore.*

Comment: Well, you *can* have spaces, just not all commands (esp. Unix) handle them properly. Folders and jobs both have "Display Name" option, so make the job w/o spaces and change the Display Name after if you choose.